# check session on server with Vercel and NextAuth

Tags: next.js, server-side, vercel, next-auth, http-status-code-504

I made a blog in which I want to verify if the user is admin before accessing the page to create a post. It works perfectly fine on the localhost but when I deploy it on vercel, it ends up with error 504 with no more informations in the logs.

I change the `NEXTAUTH_URL` with the one vercel gave to me (https).

Here is my code for the NewPostPage

```
const NewPostPage = (props) => {
  if (props.messageError) {
    console.log("Error auth: " + props.messageError);
  }
  return (
    <div className={classes.pageContainer}>
      <NewPostForm />
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewPostPage

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  try {
    return await requireAuthentification(context, "admin", ({ session }) => {
      return {
        props: { session, messageError: null },
      }
    })
  }
  catch (error) {
    return {
      props: {
        messageError: error
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the requireAuthentification function:

```
const requireAuthentification = async (context, levelAcces = "public", callback) => {
    const session = await unstable_getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions)
    if (!session) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/',
                permanent: false,
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        let user = [];
        const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("email", "==", session.user.email));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        user = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
        if (user.level !== levelAcces) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/',
                    permanent: false,
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return callback({ session });
}

export default requireAuthentification
```

I tried without the getServerSideProps and it work (with no route security). I am pretty sure the issue is from unstable_getServerSession but I am not sure, because with `GetSession` it is the same. The log on vercel aren't very helpful (see image), even if I tried with try catch and console.log to debug it.
[image: error on browser]
[image: error on vercel logs]

Why my code is working on localhost but not on Vercel, even if the rest of it, like the authentification with google part, works ? How can I debug my app ?

Comment: Try to wrap those await in try {} catch {} block , and return something when error happen so the timeout doesn't happen , also console.log that error so you can start debuging

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying, I finaly gave up this method and now I check the user authentification on the client side with `useSession()` which works well.